# Magento - Add Button to Sales Order View Page (Observer/Event)

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I'm trying to add a custom printing button (like print invoice) on the Sales Order View page (***Sales > Orders > Order #... view***).

I've done this successfully with a  but now have two modules that  that same  page. Therefore I'm trying to do the **Observer/Event** method and am running into trouble.

This is what I have for the *Mass Action printing* and it works great (previous page only (Sales > Orders).

```
$block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

// Mass Action Printing option
if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
     && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
     {
        $block->addItem('test_mass_print', array(
            'label' => 'Print Test',
            'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('orderforms/order/pdfTest'),
        ));
      }
```

Now when I try to add the button for the **Product View** page (under the same function):

```
// Order View Page button
        if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        {
            $this->_addButton('test_print', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Test'),
                'onclick'   => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('orderforms/order/print'),
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
```

I keep getting errors like this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Company_Test_Model_Observer::_addButton() in app/code/local/Company/Test/Model/Observer.php on line 24
```

I've tried:

- $block->_addButton
- $block->_addItem

but nothing seems to work. **Why is this not working???**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it a little bit after I posted. The solution for me was the following:

```
// Order View Page button
        if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        {
            $block->addButton('test_print', array(
                'label'     => 'Test',
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $block->getUrl('html/sales_order/print') . '\')',
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento, any class function starting with an underscore is defined as private or protected -- it's the naming convention the core team uses -- so you cannot call it from outside the class. This is why $block->_addButton() does not work.

The good news is you can call $block->addButton() (no underscore). This is the public method that Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container provides you.

Also, you can't call addButton() from $this, because $this is pointing to your observer class, which doesn't have an addButton() method defined (which is what your error is saying).

Comment: Thank you Joe for your answer. I solved this before you posted but wanted to thank you for helping me to further understand my mistake! Thank you for your contribution.