# Order view page print pdf button magento

Tags: php, magento, orders

I am trying to add a print order button on the main order detail page on the magento admin. The client's old magento had a print button for the order itself (paid or unpaid, not invoice). See what it used to look like:

[image: orderbar]

I've enabled template hints in on the back end and the template file does not contain that button. I've been through several core files... The html looks like the following. How would I turn that into a php button that is applicable to the currently viewed order?

```
<button  id="id_d808fbd2d533d4e7b8e4a3fcd6274251" title="Back" type="button" class="scalable back" onclick="setLocation('http://test.animalnecessity.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/order_id/15852/key/28a65aa166da1664c65971decf3e472c/')" style="">
```

Could I implement this?  [Magento - Add Button to Sales Order View Page (Observer/Event)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691895/magento-add-button-to-sales-order-view-page-observer-event) and if so where would I put this code?

I have it set up with the typical module structure as described here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_config. My config.xml in the etc folder has the following

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <CaitlinHavener_printOrder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CaitlinHavener_printOrder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                <CaitlinHavener_printOrder>
                    <class>CaitlinHavener_printOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>orderPageButton</method>
                    <type>model</type>
                </CaitlinHavener_printOrder>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

My CaitlinHavener_printOrder.xml the following

```
<config>    
    <modules>
        <CaitlinHavener_printOrder>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </CaitlinHavener_printOrder>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and Observer.php

```
<?php
// Order View Page button    
class CaitlinHavener_printOrder_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderPageButton( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
    {
        if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        {
            $block->addButton('test_print', array(
                'label'     => 'Test',
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $block->getUrl('html/sales_order/print') . '\')',
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing $block variable initialization:
$block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'block' ); // this should be the first line of orderPageButton function. It should work after that :)

Comment: Btw you should change a few things in index.php.
1) Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); <- comment if that surrounds this line
2) ini_set('display_errors', 1); <- uncomment this line; 
These two cnages will enable logs in var/log/{system, exception}.log; it's easyer to develop that way and there won't be so many bugs in production - it's surprising how many people develop magento stores without that and then when I start working on a project and enable those logs I'm greeted with allot of errors in logs that should be fixed before production

Comment: One more thing... printOrder <- Module name should start with an upper case CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder_... It's usualy that way and you can get into some serious trouble with upper case to underscore and back automatic magento conversions on for e.g. Linux OS because of case sensitive file system. In my example I intentionaly wrote correct upper/lower cased words. I don't know if that's a problem in your case since I copied your code to my module and renamed things but just an advice in case you run into such trouble :)

Comment: Hey thank you for your help! I initialized the variable but I'm still not getting a test print button on the detail order page, nor am I seeing any errors in the log...

Comment: I wrote the code in my answer below :) Like I warned you the problem was with your module name starting with lower case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The buttons are created in Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View::__construct with $this->addButton function calls.

As for the events you could use one of them but I can't recall from the top of my head which one (if any) would be apropriate to call.

To list all the events that get triggered you could add logging into Mage::dispatchEvent function with Mage::log( $name );

With that name you could declare a listener in config.xml (under config/global/events tag path):

```
  <name_that_was_printed_by_the_above_function>
    <observers>
      <YourModuleNamespace_YourModuleName>
        <class>moduleName/observer</class>
        <method>functionName</method>
        <type>model</type>
      </YourModuleNamespace_YourModuleName>
    </observers>
  </name_that_was_printed_by_the_above_function>
```

and then create a module class Observer.php

```
class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Observer
{
    public function functionName( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'data_object' ); // this line may vary

        $block->addButton( ...stuff here... // take for reference the answer from the question you linked to
        return $this;
    }
}
```

But like I said it's possible that none of the observers will suit your needs and you'll have to find another more intrusive solution...

**Edit**

You'll probbably have to use core_block_abstract_to_html_before and have an if statement to check if it's the right block... The downside is that it gives a call overhead and an if statement overhead for every block so I'm not certain if it's the best solution but it's certainly the least intrusive so I'd probably use it (the 'data_object' should be changed to 'block' in case of this event - event is triggered in Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::toHtml the dispatchEvent line).

**Edit**

After your question update I've tested your module and like I have warned in the comments the problem is the name of your module - lower case.

app/etc/modules/CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/CaitlinHavener/PrintOrder/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>    
    <modules>
        <CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                <CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
                    <class>CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>orderPageButton</method>
                    <type>model</type>
                </CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

local/CaitlinHavener/PrintOrder/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
// Order View Page button    
class CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderPageButton( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
    {
      $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'block' );

        if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View'
            && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        {
            $block->addButton('test_print', array(
                'label'     => 'Test',
                'onclick'   => 'setLocation(\'' . $block->getUrl('html/sales_order/print') . '\')',
                'class'     => 'go'
            ));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Be carefull that you correctly name your files (watch for upper case characters) and copy the code and it should work.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my edit above and giving me a clue as to what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I'm literally copying your code verbatim to make sure I'm doing it right and changed directories and filenames to be "PrintOrder" instead of the lower case and its still not working! I do not have any new errors in the logs... next idea? lol

Comment: Hm... Don't have a next idea... I've copied the module in my development version of magento and from there straight here... You could clear cache (through admin and you could also delete the entire content of var/cache folder) and if that doesn't work list your directory structure so that I'll be able to se if there's something wrong with it... Other than that nothing comes to mind...

Comment: Wee! I was being dumb. Accidentally didn't change directory path to capital P. Buttttt.. I see the button now but It does not open pdf of anything when clicked.  The old print button had setLocation('http://test.animalnecessity.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/print/order_id/15852/key/d781363c016f66e3986b3d2a2d8e888f/')

Comment: You'll have to specify the right URL but it seems to me that it doesn't exist so you'll have to write your own controller and change onclick getUrl to return url to it. Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice has printAction and Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice has getPdf function so you can use them for reference how to implement your own print function. This answer is getting a bit long so I'd suggest that you open a new more speciffic question if you'll need help with pdf creation. I'm not certain if I have answerd your question but if I have could you mark it as the right answer?

Comment: I literary copied the code which @DomenVrankar defined(https://stackoverflow.com/a/14513335/4493831) But didnt got any success - I got the button on order view page but clicking it sends me to 404(frontend) - How did you solved - Please Share

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement to @Domen Vrankar

`adminhtml_block_html_before` will only dispatch in the admin area while `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` will dispatch in both admin and front-end

```
    <events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
            <CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
                <class>CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>orderPageButton</method>
                <type>model</type>
            </CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
```

If another module rewrite `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View` then `get_class($block)` will return the new block class eg MagePal_Guest2Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View therefore your button will no longer display

```
<?php
// Order View Page button    
class CaitlinHavener_PrintOrder_Model_Observer
{
    public function orderPageButton( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
    {
      $block = $observer->getEvent()->getData( 'block' );

        if($block->getId() == 'sales_order_view' && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
        { 
          ....
```