# Add Button to CMS_Page_Edit via Observer

Tags: magento

Ok again with Observers. I'm wanting to do something like this but from within an observer

```
$this->_addButton('newbutton', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('New Button'),
), -100);
```

currently I'm working from this dispatch event

`Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cms_page_edit_tab_main_prepare_form', array('form' => $form));`

but i'm not entirely sure im in the right spot as I am still a newb. I've tried doing what is shown here but it doesn't seem to be working [Magento - Add Button to Sales Order View Page (Observer/Event)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691895/magento-add-button-to-sales-order-view-page-observer-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry guys I did it again... I was calling the wrong dispatchEvent for what I wanted here is the one I wanted

```
adminhtml_widget_container_html_before
```

so now this code works

```
$block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

if(get_class($block) == 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cms_Page_Edit'){
    $block->addButton('newbutton', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('newbutton')
    ), -100);
}
```